# SQL Error (1093) You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause with subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

There is a stored procedure that works great!

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE temp
(
IN `valcat` INT,
IN `valsubcat` INT
)

BEGIN

DECLARE tcount INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tcount
FROM subcat sz
WHERE sz.cat_id = valcat;
CASE
    WHEN tcount > 1 THEN
        DELETE sy
        FROM subcat sy
        WHERE sy.sub_id = valsubcat;
    ELSE
        DELETE sx, c
        FROM subcat sx, cat_name c
        WHERE sx.sub_id = valsubcat AND c.cat_id = valcat;
END CASE;

END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL temp(7, 14);
```

Now I would like to get rid of 'valcat' parameter and replace it by subqueries from another table. I've rewrote my stored procedure this way:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE temp
(
IN `valsubcat` INT
)

BEGIN

DECLARE tcount INT;

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO tcount
FROM subcat sz
WHERE sz.cat_id = (SELECT sw.cat_id
                    FROM subcat sw
                    WHERE sw.sub_id = valsubcat);
CASE
    WHEN tcount > 1 THEN
        DELETE sy
        FROM subcat sy
        WHERE sy.sub_id = valsubcat;
    ELSE
        DELETE sx, c
        FROM subcat sx, cat_name c
        WHERE sx.sub_id = valsubcat AND c.cat_id = (SELECT sv.cat_id
                                                    FROM subcat sv
                                                    WHERE sv.sub_id = valsubcat);
END CASE;

END //

DELIMITER ;

CALL temp(14);
```

...but now I've got the message:

> ''SQL Error (1093) in statement #3: You can't specify target table
> 'sx' for update in FORM clause''

P.S. I also have an additional question: will the performance decrease when using the second variant of the procedure?

Comment: This looks as an attempt to remove related rows from the tables which have not FOREIGN KEY reference between them. Recommendation - create correct FOREIGN key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` action and remove rows from "parent" table only - related rows from "slave" will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
DELETE sx, c
FROM subcat sx, cat_name c
WHERE sx.sub_id = valsubcat AND c.cat_id = (SELECT sv.cat_id
                                            FROM subcat sv
                                            WHERE sv.sub_id = valsubcat);
```

is wrong and must be replaced with something like

```sql
DELETE sx, c
FROM subcat sx
JOIN cat_name c ON sx.sub_id = valsubcat
JOIN subcat sv ON c.cat_id = sv.cat_id AND sv.sub_id = valsubcat;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! What do you think about performance in this case?

Comment: @Gurgen By fact you have cartesian, so the performance won't be good. See the comment to the question.